# How to define CSS style for fields marked as required?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an application that is AngularJS and Bootstrap, although I am not sure if it is relevant. I want to define CSS style for required fields. I see many examples if the field has `class='required'`, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141854/adding-asterisk-to-required-fields-in-bootstrap-3):

```
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
   content:"*";
   color:red;
}
```

However, is it possible to do the same if the field has `required='required'`, but doesn't have `required` class?

As a practical matter, I have a field that is conditionally required using `ng-required='chkChecked'` and while I can also add `ng-class={'required': chkChecked}` I would prefer to avoid it if possible

**Update** just to clarify - I want to style the field if it has "required" attribute *regardless* whether it has `required` class. My initial question could be interpreted that I want to style the element if it is required, *but doesn't have required class*. That's not the case. Sorry.

Also, I would prefer to put an asterisk on the label attached to the input field, rather than, say, a red border attached to the field itself (which can be accomplished by `input[:required]` (that I didn't know about). I did try `.form-group:required`, but for some reason it doesn't do anything, although I see `<div class="form-group" required="required">` in F12

Comment: can you please add HTML code about input tag.

Comment: you mean to say by checking the required attribute of input type and adding `*` `<input type="text" name="usrname" required>` ?

Comment: *if the field has required='required'* - In the linked thread it is the `div` which has the class and not the field. Are you saying your HTML has the required attribute on the `div`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood you correctly it is possible like this.

```css
input[required="required"]:not(.required) {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="required" required="required"></input>
<input type="text" required="required"></input>
```

**EDIT based on the modified question:**

Maybe this would be the answer you are looking for.

```css
.form-group[required="required"] input:not(.required) {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.form-group[required="required"] input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form-group[required="required"] label:after { 
  content:" *"; 
  color: red;
}

/* With only the required attribute */

.form-group[required] input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.form-group[required] label:after { 
  content:" *"; 
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" required="required">
  <label for="test1">Required</label>
  <input id="test1" type="text" required="required"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group" required="required">
  <label for="test2">Required</label>
  <input id="test2" type="text" class="required"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group" required="required">
  <label for="test3">Required</label>
  <input id="test3" type="text"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group" required="required">
  <label for="test4">Required</label>
  <input id="test4" type="text" class="required" required="required"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group" required="required">
  <label for="test5">Required</label>
  <input id="test5" type="text" class="required"></input>
</div>
<div class="form-group" required="required">
  <label for="test6">Required</label>
  <input id="test6" type="text"></input>
</div>
<h5>With only required attribute as suggested in the comments for the possibility to help someone in the future</h5>
<div class="form-group" required>
  <label for="test6">Required</label>
  <input id="test6" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

There's multiple possibilities and hopefully you can find the best that suites your needs.

Comment: From question it looks like OP is trying add the * symbol using `:after` element. If that is the case, this won't work. Pseudo-elements cannot be added to input elements.

Comment: @Harry you could be right. I just based my answer to this line "However, is it possible to do the same if the field has required='required', but doesn't have required class?". My snippet does the job for this, that's why I made my answer :)

Comment: @thepio - I realize that my initial question was somewhat misleading; I put an update. I think I can start from your answer, but if you have additional guidance - I would appreciate!

Comment: Ok I updated my answer and hopefully it's now what you need :)

Comment: @Felix: You don't really need to specify the attribute as `required=required`. It is a boolean property and just `required` is enough. e.g. `<input required>` or `<div required>`. You need to accommodate that as well, which `.form-group[required="required"]` selector will not cut. All you need is simply `div[required]` or `div.form-group[required]`. See here - https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/aa24x2eq/ and check how the last label doesn't get an asterisk.

Comment: Thanks, @Abhitalks, you are correct. That said, AngularJS `ng-required` generates `required="required"`; but looks like both `.form-group[required="required"]` and `.form-group[required]` do what I want

Comment: Either way is good and I usually use only the required attribute on an input but in SO the answer always depends on the question. Of course recommending new ways and better ways to do things is always a nice thing :)

Answer (score 7):

```css
:required:not(.required) {
  background-color: #aca1e4;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="required" required="required" />
<input type="text" required="required" />
```

[:required](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/required/)

[:not](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)

Comment: it would be good, if you can add some description or explain the functionality

Comment: external links should be included as a reference but the answer should have some  basic information. just add explanation about the css selector and how it fixes OP's problem, it will help others in future as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
.form-group .required {
   content:"*";
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the :required pseudo-selector class.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control"  required/>
```

this input field will not accept null or empty string.
if it will empty then input box border will appear in red color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with CSS3. In case you don't, just to say that a great feature of CSS3 are **selectors**. Something like jQuery selectors, but even better because there's no programming involved.

Here my page of reference, [W3Schools - CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Hope it will help you.

*Note:* W3Schools has many more contents related to web technologies. Page also applies the standards of the consortium W3C.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with CSS3 and selectors. But thanks, anyway